# How to put my Java Slick StateBasedGame on a website

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

I have made a 2D java game using Slick and it extends StateBasedGame, it does not extend JApplet so it is not really a real application but from the link bellow it shows that StateBasedGame is part of the Slick API and it can be used as an applet if the html code is coded correctly, here is the link:

http://ninjacave.com/slickapplet

I tried modifying it to fit my code and came up with the following:

```
    <applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader… 
archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" 
codebase="." 
width="640" height="480">

    <param name="al_title" value="Ham Blaster"> 
    <param name="al_main" value="org.newdawn.slick.AppletGameConta… 
    <param name="game" value="org.javagame.Game">

    <param name="al_jars" value="racegame.jar, lwjgl.jar, slick.jar"> 

    <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar"> 
    <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar"> 
    <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar"> 

    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"> 
    </applet>
```

I copied it and edited what needed to be edited such as adding things like my main class which is Game, my package which is javagame and my jar file containing all of my lass's and images (made using eclipse) which is racecar.jar and came up with the html code shown above.

After doing all of this I get an error saying the following when I run my html code:

ClassNotFoundException org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader

I have not done anything else apart from put that code in html and download the latest version of lwjgl-2.8.5, I cannot find lwjgl_util_applet_AppletLoader anywhere in there, the closest thing I can find is lwjgl_util_applet, how do I fix my code so that my game works as an applet.

Comment: **org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader** must be part of one of the main jar files. I would assume it should be in lwjgl.jar. Did you have all the mentioned jar files present together with your jar file? The missing of the appropriate jar file would cause such an error.

Comment: The download that I have was from here: http://lwjgl.org/download.php the lwjgl-2.8.5 I extracted it using winrar and have a folder on my desktop now, if I go inside it, there are more folders, I go into jar I find many jar files, lwjgl.jar is inside there also if that is what you are asking, I am very new to this so it might just be a simple problem and I am over complicating it.

Comment: Basically all I did was make a game, the main class extends StateBasedGame so I had been told that forum post linked in my original post will make my Java game into an app without having to modify my Java code, so I made a .jar file of my project in eclipse and downloaded lwjgl then basically copied all of the code from the forum to notepad++ editing what needed to be edited, I thought I had followed all of the steps correctly but I still get errors.

Comment: Hm... From my understanding you should have the HTML file holding the applet, as well as the lwjgl_util_applet.jar and the JAR file that contains your game (is that racegame.jar?) in the same directory to make this work. Is that the case for you?

Comment: Yes racegame.jar is the game but it is not in the same directory as my lwjgl files, is there a set place where they should all be? EDIT: I tried moving the racecar.jar with the lwjgl files and got the error org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader...archive=

Comment: Is this the full error - or was something truncated on your post: "error org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader...archive= –"